# Validating user input to prevent duplicate ID with added feature

Tags: javascript

I am building an app with an add and search function. On the add function, I have pattern-'nd' it to [Validating user input to prevent duplicate ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897243/validating-user-input-to-prevent-duplicate-id) . On my search function, the user can update the data they have inputted in the add function. However, when the data is updating, the validation for duplicate ID also works, preventing the user to update the data. I want to disable it when the user is on the search function. Thank you.

```js
  Z = 0;

function SaveDebt() {
  ANu = document.getElementById("ANu").value;
  ANa = document.getElementById("ANa").value;
  CN = document.getElementById("CN").value;
  DOT = document.getElementById("DOT").value;
  DOP = document.getElementById("DOP").value;
  AP = document.getElementById("AP").value;
  Prodc = document.getElementById("Prodc").value;
  Prodn = document.getElementById("Prodn").value;
  Produ = document.getElementById("Produ").value;
  Prodq = document.getElementById("Prodq").value;

  anumbercheck = AlertME(ANu, /^[2][0][2][1-9]{1}-\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}$/, "Invalid Account Number! Please follow this format YYYY-nnn. The year (YYYY) must be 2021 onwards.")
  anamecheck = AlertME(ANa, /^[A-Z][A-z. ]{4,49}$/g, "Invalid name! Please try again.")
  cnumbercheck = AlertME(CN, /^[0][9]\d{9}$/g, "Mobile number is invalid!")
  dotcheck = AlertME(DOT, /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-]\d{4}$/, "Date of Transaction is invalid! Please follow this format DD-MM-YYYY")
  dopcheck = AlertME(DOP, /^$|^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-]\d{4}$/, "Date of Payment is invalid! Please follow this format DD-MM-YYYY")
  apcheck = AlertME(AP, /(^[0-9]\d{0,5}[.][0-9]{2}$)|(^[1-9]\d{0,5}[.][0-9]{2}$)/, "Amount paid is invalid! Please put two decimal places");

  prodctsk = AlertME(Prodc, /^$|^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}$/, "The Product Code is invalid! Please follow this format AA-nn")
  prodntsk = AlertME(Prodn, /^$|^[a-z0-9 ,.']+$/i, "The Product Name is invalid!")
  prodptsk = AlertME(Produ, /^$|^([1-9][.][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9][.][0-9]{2}|1[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}|200)$/, "The Product Price is invalid! Minimum amount is PhP1, Maximum amount is PhP200 with two decimal places")
  prodqtsk = AlertME(Prodq, /^$|^(10|[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[.][0-9]{0,2}?)$/, "The Product Quantity for Item 1 is invalid! Minimum is 1, Maximum is 10")

  if (anumbercheck == true && anamecheck == true && cnumbercheck == true && dotcheck == true && dopcheck == true && apcheck == true && prodctsk == true && prodntsk == true && prodptsk == true && prodqtsk == true) {
    if (ANuDB.indexOf(ANu) == -1) {
      if (Z == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < ANuDB.length; i++) {
          if (ANu == ANuDB[i]) {
            ANaDB[i] = ANa;
            CNDB[i] = CN;
            DOTDB[i] = DOT;
            DOPDB[i] = DOP;
            APDB[i] = AP;
            ProdcDB[i] = Prodc;
            ProdnDB[i] = Prodn;
            ProduDB[i] = Produ;
            ProdqDB[i] = Prodq;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        ANuDB.push(ANu);
        ANaDB.push(ANa);
        CNDB.push(CN);
        DOTDB.push(DOT);
        DOPDB.push(DOP);
        APDB.push(AP);
        ProdcDB.push(Prodc);
        ProdnDB.push(Prodn);
        ProduDB.push(Produ);
        ProdqDB.push(Prodq);
      }
      alert("Records for Account No: " + ANu + " are successfully saved.\n\n\nYou will be redirected to the homepage.");
      document.getElementById("delbutton").style = "display: none"
      document.getElementById("Resseett").click();
      document.getElementById("Cannceel").click();
    } else {
      alert("Account Number already exists! Please change the Account Number")
    }
  }
  Z = 0;
}

  function SearchDebt() {
    ANu = prompt("Enter Account No:");

    if (ANu === "") {
      alert("You have entered an invalid Account Number! Please try again.");
    } else {
      x = ANuDB.length;
      var xID = -1;

      for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (ANu == ANuDB[i])
          xID = i;
      }
      if (xID == -1) {
        alert("We can't find any record of Account Number: " + ANu + "!");
        document.getElementById("Cannceel").click();
      } else {
        document.getElementById("ANu").value = ANuDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("ANa").value = ANaDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("CN").value = CNDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("DOT").value = DOTDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("DOP").value = DOPDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("AP").value = APDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("Prodc").value = ProdcDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("Prodn").value = ProdnDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("Produ").value = ProduDB[xID];
        document.getElementById("Prodq").value = ProdqDB[xID];

        Z = 1;
        CalculateProd();
        document.getElementById("detaiills").click();
        document.getElementById("delbutton").style = "display: visible"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi! Your snippet doesn't do anything even when I remove the unnecessary script tags. Do you have some HTML to work on as well?

Comment: Hey OP, could you please comment a bit your code so it's easier for us to work on the answer? Also, Imo there's a poor variable naming... Don't worry about using longer names for them! A variable name should describe what it is!